# Android drawing and painting app for creating comics

Tags: android, drawing, graphic-design, pixel-graphics

I have Android tablet that support multi levels of pressure with stylus pen. I need an app can help me create comics that has tools for drawing and painting quickly and easily. Please advise

Comment: Not using any such, but maybe one out of my app listing for [Painting apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/paint) fits? [Sketchbook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adsk.sketchbook) for example, or [Draw, Sketch pad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drawing.pad.desk.app.coloring.book.paint.sketch)? [MemeTastic](https://f-droid.org/packages/io.github.gsantner.memetastic/) looks promising as well.